# How to refer tag value in yaml

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

```
server: 
-  import: 
      cmd: GET GPRS <gprsEn> <gprsVa> <gprsSt>
-  update: 
      gprsEn: 1
      gprsVa: 202
      gprsSt: reegan
```

This is my yaml file how to refer gprsEn,gprsVa and gprsSt value in `GET GPRS 1 202 reegan` i need a output is like

```
GET GPRS 1 202 reegan
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no string substitution defined anywhere in the YAML specification, so you have to do this yourself e.g. by doing:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
server:
-  import:
      cmd: GET GPRS <gprsEn> <gprsVa> <gprsSt>
-  update:
      gprsEn: 1
      gprsVa: 202
      gprsSt: reegan
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)

cmd = data['server'][0]['import']['cmd'].replace('<', '{').replace('>', '}')
keywords = data['server'][1]['update']
print(cmd.format(**keywords))
```

which prints exactly the output you want:

```
GET GPRS 1 202 reegan
```

You can of course also expand the parser, but it would still need to go through hoops to specify the source of the keyword/value expansion which in your case is non-relevant (i.e. not some toplevel mapping).

Comment: Thanks for solution, if any possible is there in partially write in yaml file.i have more the 10 map is there, i have change particular map value

Comment: @ReeganMiranda Yes you can write YAML files, if you use my library (ruamel.yaml) with RoundTrip mode without loss of data. If you want to partly write, or write partly resolved (with the above method) data you can do so. You can write the result out, including comments etc, as long as you don't replace complete dicts with new ones (ie. only update an existing keys value)